# React: Triggering useFetch Hook inside a loop in a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

I have a standard useFetch hook. In addition, I have an array of objects that for every one of them I need to make an API call with a unique key and insert it into a new Array with its old properties and new properties from the API response, the problem is that I can't call the useFetch inside the loop or/and in the useEffect because of the Hooks rules, Currently, the fetch is happening in the sub-component but I was told its not the best practice, Id be happy for some help.

the useFetch hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
}

export default useFetch;
```

The Component

```
const Favorites = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({});
  const [updatedFavorites,setUpdatedFavorites] = useState([]);
  const favoritesFromStorage = getFavorites();
  
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(url);

  useEffect(() => {
    favoritesFromStorage.forEach((fav) => {
      const url = `${CURRENT_API_URL}/${fav.key}?apikey=${API_KEY}&details=true`;
      setUrl(url);
      if (data && data.length > 0) {
        setCurrentWeather({...data[0]})
      }
      const newFav = {
        ...fav,
        WeatherIcon:currentWeather.WeatherIcon,
        WeatherText:currentWeather.WeatherText,
        Temperature:currentWeather.Temperature,
      }
      setUpdatedFavorites((prev) => {
        prev,
        newFav
      });

    });
  }, []);
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      setCurrentWeather({...data[0]})
    }
  }, [data]);




  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

};
```